# jQuery Photo Tag not displaying properly

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to create a photo tagging system, however I'm running into a small problem. When I click on the add tag button, the tag box doesn't show up in the correct position. Every time I show the tag, it is pinned to the bottom left corner of the image regardless of where I tag on the photo. I've logged the x & y coordinates and they are correct, it's just the box that doesn't display properly. Also, the exact same code runs fine locally but not when I deploy. Any thoughts? [The link to the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/filkinsteez/vATcn/24/)

```
var addTag = function(){
    var position = $('#mapper').position();
    var pos_x = position.left;
    var pos_y = position.top;
    var pos_width = $('#mapper').width();
    var pos_height = $('#mapper').height();


    $('#planetmap').append('<div class="tagged"  style="width:'+pos_width+';height:'+
        pos_height+';left:'+pos_x+';top:'+pos_y+';" ><div   class="tagged_box" style="width:'+pos_width+';height:'+
        pos_height+';display:none;" ></div><div class="tagged_title" style="top:'+(pos_height+5)+';display:none;" >'+
        $("#title").val()+'</div></div>')


    $("#mapper").hide();
    $("#title").val('');
    $("#form_panel").hide();


};

var showTags = function(){
    $(".tagged_box").css("display","block");
    $(".tagged").css("border","5px solid #EEE");
    $(".tagged_title").css("display","block");
};
```

Comment: there was an extra `});` with no matching close brackets can you check the integrity of the code snippet posted?

Answer (score 0):

CSS requires you to define units when referring to size and location, otherwise it discards it. You need to include "px" after your location values.

```
$('#planetmap').append('<div class="tagged"  style="width:'+pos_width+'px;height:'+
            pos_height+'px;left:'+pos_x+'px;top:'+pos_y+'px;" ><div   class="tagged_box" style="width:'+pos_width+'px;height:'+
            pos_height+'px;display:none;" ></div><div class="tagged_title" style="top:'+(pos_height+5)+'px;display:none;" >'+
            $("#title").val()+'</div></div>');
```

Make sure you are loading the dependent scripts when you deploy your code.